# How to merge between branches

Tags: svn, version-control

Currently I am using svn, with stable trunk release and multiple development branch. I intended to do continuous integration with configuration between beach branches.

Say that I have the following structure:

```
        trunk
     /        \
 feature_1  feature_2
```

As the svn way, I find it hard to merge between branches feature_1 and feature_2 without merging to trunk. Is there any proper way to handle this?

Comment: Cheeky response: switch SCMs xD

Comment: @user2864740 which one?

Comment: I use Hg, but Git is very popular. The core merge premise (for really any of these systems, barring how simple or complicated it is made) is to create a delta between F1/F2 and graft (FSVO) the change-set across.

Answer (score 0):

We merge feature branch x to y by/over trunk. 
To mark stable trunk revisions you can use `tags`.
This method has proven itself over many years and works fine in your project.
Merging feature branch to another feature branch was sometimes hard in terms of merge conflicts.